# How to close headlessui-vue Popover from code

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css

I have a vue component that shows a popover with some content using the headlessui for vue and I want to close it when I click on the content. I have read the [headlessui/vue docs](https://headlessui.dev/vue/popover)  for manually handling the opening and closing of a Popover which states:

> If you'd rather handle this yourself (perhaps because you need to add an extra wrapper element for one reason or another), you can pass a static prop to the PopoverPanel to tell it to always render, and then use the open slot prop to control when the panel is shown/hidden yourself.

I have:

```
<Popover v-slot="{ open }">
    <PopoverButton>
    </PopoverButton>
    <div v-if="open">
        <PopoverPanel static>
        </PopoverPanel>
    </div>
</Popover>
```

and it works so far but I want to close the Popover when I click the some content inside it, essentially I want to know how I can access that "open" in my script. I'm quite new to vue so maybe I'm missing something simple.

Comment: See discussion here:
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/issues/427 
Even though you are already participating there, this may help other people.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One workaround would be to manually click the PopoverButton inside of the panel.

Here's an example how that could work in React:

```js
const buttonRef = useRef();

<Popover>
  <Popover.Button ref={buttonRef}>Click me</Popover.Button>
  <Popover.Panel>
    <button onClick={() => buttonRef.current?.click()}>Content</button>
  </Popover.Panel>
</Popover>
```

Comment: hey I forgot to come back and thank you for this answer. It was helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I'm using in Vue3.
Can use a `close` slot to make a close button inside content.

```
<script setup>
  import { Popover, PopoverButton, PopoverPanel } from '@headlessui/vue'
</script>
<template>
  <Popover>
    <PopoverButton>Open/Close out of Content</PopoverButton>
    <PopoverPanel v-slot="{ close }">
      <button @click="close">Close Button in Content</button>
    </PopoverPanel>
  </Popover>
</template>
```